# Mask Url from path to subdomain using NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, proxypass, cloudflare

I want to achieve url rewrite as such:
`https://documentation.domain.com/login`  to `https://app.domain.com/login`
`https://api.domain.com/login` to `https://app.domain.com/login`

, any sudomain with url {anything}.domain.com/login to `https://app.domain.com/login`

`https://app.domain.com/sdks` to `https://documentation.domain.com/sdks` (with all query parameters preserved)
`https://api.domain.com/sdks` to `https://documentation.domain.com/sdks` (with all query parameters preserved)
, any sudomain with url {anything}.domain.com/sdks to `https://documentation.domain.com/sdks`

`https://app.domain.com/restApi` to `https://documentation.domain.com/restApi` (with all query parameters preserved)
`https://api.domain.com/restApi` to `https://documentation.domain.com/restApi` (with all query parameters preserved)
, any sudomain with url {anything}.domain.com/restApi to `https://documentation.domain.com/restApi`

All above domains & sub domains are behind cloudflare with enabled SSL in mode Full Strict.
How can I achieve this ?
No matter what I do I always get "Too many redirects"

Certificate with key from cloudflare config (works):

```
ssl_certificate     /home/company/domain/ssl/push_node_cloudflare.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/company/domain/ssl/push_node_cloudflare_privatekey.key;
```